# Why does git add my commits on a local branch to my master branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch, commit

I keep running into this problem where I will create a branch, add files, write stuff, etc. and then when I switch to master the commits are there? It happens randomly, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I usually do the following process:

- Use `git branch` to make sure I'm in the right branch.
- Use `git add .` and then `git commit -m "message"`.
- Do `git checkout master`.

When I switch to master, the changes are still there. Anybody else have this problem?

Comment: Are the changes there as a new commit? Are they working copy changes, e.g. perhaps files that are being ignored by Git? Please post the output of `git status` the next time you encounter this.

Comment: When I do git status on the master branch it says it is up to date, just like it does on the branch. It's as if I've committed to both of them at the same time. None of the files were added to my .gitignore file.

Comment: What command do you use to create a branch? Be aware that `git branch <new_branch>` creates a branch, but does not check it out.

Comment: Well, it would say "up to date": after you commit to another branch there are no longer any changes for `status` to display. Do your changes appear in a *commit* on the `master` branch?

Comment: I use git checkout -b <new_branch> to create a new branch. But I use git branch to check what branch I am on before committing. Chris - Good question. The first time it did and this second time it did not, but the files were still there.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up with unwanted changes to your master branch, you can stash the changes by using the following command:

```
git stash
```

These stashes are stacked for later use. You can pop the most recent stash off the stack onto the same or another branch by using:

```
git stash pop
```

There are other ways to reuse older stashes. Refer to the Git documentation for further info.